# Unserializing data error

Tags: php, serialization, pdo

I could not found why php say me :

```
Warning: Insufficient data for unserializing - 5468 required, 226 present
```

I'm trying to serialize and after unserialize some objects and data.

Maybe is it too big ?

Edit :

Since it not possible to post the code because it is too much complex, i will explain what i'm doing :

I'm serializing data to save it into session. 
I save in the session a Basket object which cames with a list of product (objects). The product class implements Serialize to avoid saving PDO object (which return an error while serializing) which is in the class for some ORM features.

Here are the implementation methods of Serialize interface :

```
public function serialize() {
    $serialized = \serialize(array(
        '_vars' => $this->getVars(), 
        '_returnNullIfEmpty' => $this->_returnNullIfTempty, 
        '_dataModel' => $this->getDataModel()
    ));

    return $serialized;
}

public function unserialize($data) {
    $unserialized = \unserialize($data);

    $this->setVars($unserialized['_vars']);
    $this->_returnNullIfEmpty = $unserialized['_returnNullIfEmpty'];
    $this->_dataModel = $unserialized['_dataModel'];
}
```

I have noticed that i have always this error under the first :

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 10503 of 10968 bytes in ...
```

Comment: Maybe you write us the code producing such error? ^^

Comment: What are you using to serialize? Also I doubt it is too big, since the warning says there's not enough data.

Comment: I'm using serialize() to serialize

Comment: It seems that it is a problem of encoding that failed whith serialize. I found a solution : using rawurlencode after serialize and rawurldecode before unserialize.

Comment: Make the field *binary* in your database, then you do not run into encoding problems.

Comment: Right, but i'm putting this in a file :s